# Meteor CSV file upload

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am new to meteor i making app to upload  large csv file, when I run the app  files are uploaded to my home directory (ubuntu)and to the Mongodb collection I can see it with robomongo ,after that i am receiving this 
error on the console (STDERR) Error: ENOENT, open '/imports/tdcdata.csv' 
I have changed  ./ ,~/ , home/user/imports it does not work. Thanks for your contribution in advance;
here is my code :

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'uploadFile': function(fileid, filename) {
    var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
    var file = Uploads.find({
      _id: fileid
    });
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
      var filepath = '~/imports/' + filename;
      //var filepath = '/imports/uploads-' + fileid + '-' + filename;
      CSV().from.stream(
          fs.createReadStream(filepath), {
            'escape': '\\'
          })
        .on('record', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(row, index) {
          Album.insert({
            'Account Number': row[0],
            'Album Title': row[1],
            'Track Artist': row[2],
            'Track Title': row[3],
            'ISRC': row[4],
            'Source UPC': row[5],
          })
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        }))
        .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .on('end', function(count) {

        })
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you please clean up your code so that it's easier to read? That will give you better answers here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FS.debug = true` to get some information like path.

```
FS.debug = true

Upload = new FS.Collection("uploads", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("uploads")]
});
```

The path is `var filepath = process.env.PWD + "/.meteor/local/cfs/files/uploads/uploads-" + fileid + "-" + filename;`

I think there is another way to write this, but I think it works.